# How to split up Bootstrap row width equally between columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a bootstrap row, which contains several col-md-1 Bootstrap columns (the amount can vary but never exceeds 12). In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10929/) you can see an example of what I mean.

Currently if I have four columns (like in my fiddle), they float left and do not use up the full width of the row:

[image]

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    ...
  </div>
```

What I want to have, is that the columns keep the same width as above, however they get spread out equally throughout the row. Remember, there can be any number of col-md-1s between 1 and 12! The result width four columns should look something like this:

[image]

Further requirements and information:

1. I'm using this in my AngularJS application, so I'd prefer non-jQuery
   solutions
2. If it's in anyway possible, IE9+ support would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to have dynamic number of columns, flexbox is the best way to go.

As you required, it supports [**IE10+**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Adding for cross browser support */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.col-sm-1 {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">4</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">4</div>

    <div class="col-sm-1">5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The link you provided (http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) says it doesn't support IE9 though.

Comment: Oops! Support is from IE10 onwards. But you can use [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/docs/#flexbox) and use a different code for IE9 fallback.

Answer (score 3):

You can use offset method

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
<div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
<div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
<div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Try this,, this may help  you 
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L39chhe3/)

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do this just with bootstrap and css pushing the columns.

One possible solution can be:

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-push-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-push-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-push-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.row {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0 4%;
}

.col-sm-1 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/s451fq03/)