# Bootstrap 3 Fit multiple fields into one row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two fields in one row and another fields that is conditional. However, I want them to fit in one row.

For example:
[image: Three fields]

and
[image: Two fields]

So how do I make the fields fit in one row, regardless whether it has two or three fields?

```
1)<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-*"></div>
     <div class="col-md-*"></div>
     <div class="col-md-*"></div>
</div>

2)<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-*"></div>
     <div class="col-md-*"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way that both of those will fit in one row equally so that in the first case, the asterisk will be equal to 4 and the second case, it will be 6?

Comment: Are you asking how to justify 2-3 form components on one row, or just to make them fit? If it's the latter, you could set the components' classes to `.col-md-4`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split up Bootstrap row width equally between columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939153/how-to-split-up-bootstrap-row-width-equally-between-columns)

Comment: Yes, that's usually what I do, ".col-md-4" would work if I knew whether I would have two fields, but sometimes, it's two fields, then it needs to be set to ".col-md-6".